# How do I delete a camera in a blender scene I downloaded

Tags: scene

There is a blender scene I just downloaded and it has a camera in it. Whenever I try to delete it, it deletes the whole scene. All i want is the camera to be removed[image]

Comment: Could you please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Check if the objects are parented to the camera and unparent it first if it is so.

Comment: @moonboots Not necessary, it's an instanced collection as the screenshot shows.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth If the child object is not selected, deleting a parent object will not delete the child. Only transformations that are made in relation to the parent object get lost if you delete it.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but I wanted to make sure  ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used *Append* to import the collection into your scene. And in the *Append* options "Instance Collection" was enabled. You can see it from the orange collection symbol in the *Outliner*. This is just an empty which instances the collection.

[image: instanced collection]

And this means you just have a linked duplicate to the original collection in your scene which can only be changed as a whole, but only transformations like moving, rotating, scaling. You cannot edit individual objects or meshes or delete individual parts, only the collection altogether.

To be able to manipulate individual objects you have to convert the instance into real objects. You can do this by selecting the collection, then from the *3D Viewport* menu choose *Object* > *Apply* > *Make Instances Real* or in the viewport hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Make Instances Real*.

[image: make instances real]

In the tool options on the bottom left of the viewport you can then choose if you want to parent the converted objects to the empty from which the instance came and if you want to keep the original hierarchy of the original collection when creating the individual objects. You can do this by enabling the options.

[image: tool options]